# Cannot connect to remote jmx server using jvisualvm or jconsole (netcat working)

Tags: visualvm, jconsole, jvisualvm

I have a spark application running on a remote server and I need to get its heap dump for performance purposes. I was able to run the jstatd service on the remote machine and connect to it using visualvm. However jstatd does not enable heap dump of remote machines (I am using visual vm 1.3.8).

To resolve this I started my application with the following extra options:

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=54321 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=54320 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$HOSTNAME"
```

After running this I used netstat to gather all open ports by the process and got the following output:

```
sudo netstat -lp | grep 37407
tcp        0      0 *:54321                     *:*                         LISTEN      37407/java
tcp        0      0 *:54320                     *:*                         LISTEN      37407/java
```

To check if the remote port was accessible through my local machine I used the netcat utility and the connection with remote host on both 54321 and 54320 was successful.

However when I try to connect to the host using visualvm or jconsole it fails to connect. Visual vm reports the following error:

```
cannot connect to hostname:54321 using service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://hostname:54321/jmxrmi
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

in order to enable jconsole connection : try adding this flag

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
```

and in order to a heap dump, you don't need to connect via jconsole, just use jmap:

```
 $>jmap -dump:format=b,live,file=<filename> <process-id>
```

and finally, if spark has a daemon controlling it, make sure it doesn't kill the process during the heap dump creation.

Comment: My problem was different. I need to run this on an application running Spark. The spark-submit command along with the jmx options needed to be done on the same machine as the application master. Otherwise the service runs but does not behave as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $HOSTNAME is the hostname of the server you are running spark submit from, you need to set to the hostname of the machine the spark driver runs on:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<hostname of spark driver>
```

BTW, This is the reason it only worked for you when your spark application and the spark submit was on the same server.